# Duplicate question, but out of date?

Tags: discussion

Sometimes I am searching for questions related to current Ubuntu release (e.g. 12.04) and end up in finding the exact question but being closed, as this question has been previously asked for (10.10). As software systems will change over time, the optimal answer to the same question might be different for different Ubuntu releases. Of course I know that there are tag's for the releases I could use for my question. But this does not seem to be regarded: [installation on SSD](https://askubuntu.com/questions/129480/installation-on-ssd) Of course the top answer there was recently edited, but I am unsure as the older question explicitly targets 10.10.

So what I am asking here:

1. **How do you handle this "out-of-date" problem currently.**
2. **Are there currently any plans to improve this situation.**

I know this are two questions inside of one post, *BUT* they are so closely related I think I can expect an answer of both within one answer. I don't wanted to offend anybody, I am just asking! And if this question is a duplicate too: Sorry I didn't found the duplicate.

Cheers, and thanks for your notes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is not an unique situation, it happens all the time and has you say software changes.

Did it change so much that needs updating of the information? Fix it, flag it for fixing, add a bounty to it and explain it needs updated information, make it better!
This does not need improving, its how the site works.

ie: if [Installing Ubuntu on a SSD](https://askubuntu.com/questions/19376/installing-ubuntu-on-a-ssd) does not cover all the aspects of current information but its where people are redirecting duplicates to it:

- flag it to our attention that the information on that posts needs to be updated for newer systems
- start by editing the tags to remove any previous system references
- join us in our [chat rooms](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/201/ask-ubuntu-general-room) and talk to the people there, tell us that the post needs to be bumped up and updated
- if you have the chance update it your self with a newer answer, make sure that you specify the release version in you header, ie:

  - **For Ubuntu 12.04**
  - **Since Ubuntu 11.04**

In the end it is important that outdated questions are updated with more recent information if that is necessary. That is what we do, constantly, on the site and thats how the site works. If you stop it and can help, fix it, else ask someone to help you fix it. This is really important work!

Comment: +1. Another related issue I am noticing (I think its worth mentioning here, rather than raise another question). is that some people are commenting "Possible duplicate" and the target duplication has not really got a great answer or selection of answer options (even if one of them is accepted).http://askubuntu.com/questions/166757/sharing-folder-with-other-users is maybe not the best example but an example in any case. The 1st duplicate suggested hasn’t got the best answer for the asker. Maybe duplicate candidates should be fixed before they are declared fit as a response to the new question.